# Impossible to create trigger in a table with a reserved name in Oracle

Tags: oracle, keyword, database-trigger

I have a table named BLOB, and I can select, update, insert normally via SQL, but it's impossible to define a trigger for it, obviously the cause is the name.

In PL/SQL as a procedure, I work around the problem by creating a view which selects all the columns of the table, and using it in the body but it doesn't work on the table itself.

Does anyone have a solution? I cannot rename the table. Also using a synonym is out.

Structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE BLOB
(
  BLOBID           CHAR(7 BYTE)                 NOT NULL,
  OGGETTO          BLOB
)
```

The problem is related to the presence of a column of type BLOB in a table named BLOB, but only in PL/SQL environment (procs, triggers, ...)

Comment: *"but it's impossible to define a trigger for it, obviously the cause is the name."* is it? I have just created a trigger on a table called BLOB in my 18c XE instance. Straight down the hatch without a snatch. Yes, I was surprised too. So, whilst the table name is egregious bad practice doing what you want should be possible. Please post a reproducible test case, including the error message you get.

Comment: The error is about the type 'BLOB': ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
ORA-06553: PLS-488: 'BLOB' must be a type

Comment: Here is [a demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bcb766a0e7d9ed3dafc33c813c8e1642) which demonstrates that there is no apparent problem. Please post an equivalent test case which reproduces the problem you assert.

Comment: $VERSION= Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

When I attempt to create a trigger on BLOB table, I get this: 
ORA-06552: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated ORA-06553: PLS-488: 'BLOB' must be a type

Comment: You need to post **a reproducible test case**. Please look at [this code on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bcb766a0e7d9ed3dafc33c813c8e1642). It creates a table called BLOB, creates a trigger on that table, inserts a row in the table. **It works**. So the burden of proof is on you. Therefore you need to post something similar which illustrates how your situation is different. If you don't clearly explain what you're doing we cannot provide you with the help you're asking for.

Comment: I can only imagine this was an issue back in Oracle 11g that is no longer an issue in 12c and above.  No idea how you get round it though (other than a database upgrade!)

Comment: when I test, in another user of same schema, the sequence of commands as in the example code, it works fine ... but when I replicate the real case BLOB table structure, attempting to create the simple trigger results in the above mentioned error ! In the next comment I reprocduce the table ...

Comment: I have edited the message to include the structure ...

Comment: Actually the problem is related to the presence of a field of type BLOB in a table named BLOB. I have restricted to a two fields table the original, and only when I declare the field OGGETTO of type BLOB, I got the error in the trigger creation ...

Comment: You say you can't rename the table.  But *someone* can surely?  Rename it to e.g. BLOB_TABLE and then create a synonym called BLOB for it so that everything that references the table as BLOB can still do that.

Comment: Unluckly I can not change the name of the table, because it's widely used in our software ... Also, using a Synonym on BLOB table doesn't solve the problem (I think your exemple - reversed - does it) ... So I used a workaround, creating a Scheduled Job, in which I reference the table via a view, who does the work of a trigger, in an asynchronous way...